# Nested loop to match colors

Tags: sql, nested-loops

Basically I have a table of colors, now I implemented a query which matches all colors together. I was wondering is it possible to do this with a loop? (perhaps it is a nested loop).

My idea is to loop the first color with every other color and then loop the second color with every other etc. **Help is greatly appreciated**.

**My table** - contains different colors

```
       CREATE TABLE Colors
      (c_ID VARCHAR2(3) NOT NULL,
      c_NAME VARCHAR2(11));

     INSERT INTO Colors VALUES
     ('T01','RED');
     INSERT INTO Colors VALUES
     ('T02','BLUE');
     INSERT INTO Colors VALUES
     ('T03','BLACK');
     INSERT INTO Colors VALUES
     ('T04','YELLOW');
     INSERT INTO Colors VALUES
     ('T05','ORANGE');
```

The **sql query** that **I used to match different colors**:

```
         select  a.c_id as HM, s.c_id as AW
         from colors a, colors s
         where a.c_id <> s.c_id 
         order by a.c_id;
```

Comment: why you to write in loop instead it giving in one single query!!!

Comment: Yes I have done it in a single query, but like I mention I would like to know and perhaps see it in a loop (probably its nested loop) :)

Comment: for looping you have to write store procedure .

Comment: Does your DBMS support recursive queries?

Comment: Yes, it does support it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recursive query. (this is for Postgres, Your Syntax May Vary)

```
CREATE TABLE Colors
      (c_ID INTEGER NOT NULL
        , c_NAME VARCHAR
        );

     INSERT INTO Colors VALUES
     (1,'RED'), (2,'BLUE'), (3,'BLACK'), (4,'YELLOW'), (5,'ORANGE');

WITH RECURSIVE xxx AS (
        SELECT
        c1.c_ID AS last_id
        , c1.c_NAME::text AS all_colors
        FROM Colors c1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT c2.c_ID AS last_id
                , x.all_colors|| '+' || c2.c_NAME::text AS all_colors
        FROM Colors c2
        JOIN xxx x ON x.last_id < c2.c_ID
        )
SELECT all_colors
FROM xxx
        ;
```

Results:

```
CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 5
          all_colors          
------------------------------
 RED
 BLUE
 BLACK
 YELLOW
 ORANGE
 RED+BLUE
 RED+BLACK
 RED+YELLOW
 RED+ORANGE
 BLUE+BLACK
 BLUE+YELLOW
 BLUE+ORANGE
 BLACK+YELLOW
 BLACK+ORANGE
 YELLOW+ORANGE
 RED+BLUE+BLACK
 RED+BLUE+YELLOW
 RED+BLUE+ORANGE
 RED+BLACK+YELLOW
 RED+BLACK+ORANGE
 RED+YELLOW+ORANGE
 BLUE+BLACK+YELLOW
 BLUE+BLACK+ORANGE
 BLUE+YELLOW+ORANGE
 BLACK+YELLOW+ORANGE
 RED+BLUE+BLACK+YELLOW
 RED+BLUE+BLACK+ORANGE
 RED+BLUE+YELLOW+ORANGE
 RED+BLACK+YELLOW+ORANGE
 BLUE+BLACK+YELLOW+ORANGE
 RED+BLUE+BLACK+YELLOW+ORANGE
(31 rows)
```

Comment: The expanding text string is a bit clumsy, and only intended for demonstration purposes. You could use an array, if avalable.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you want all colors in a single row, or even in a single column of a single row?

The query you show, will only result in *pairs* of colors. If you want *all* colors, you need to self-join as many times as you have colors. So adding or removing a color will turn your ugly query into a broken query. In general you will have a query result, where the number of columns depends on the number of colors. This does not play well with the relational paradigm.

If you just want *all* colors as a single value, then you need to *aggregeate* colors. The query result will then be a single value, with all the colors combined, possibly separated by commas.

To aggregate things you need an *aggregate function*. Well-known aggregate functions are SUM, MIN or AVG, none of which do what you need here. What aggregate function to chose depends on your particular SQL dialect.

For oracle you may look into [pivot or xmlagg](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_converting_rows_columns.htm).

You may also consider wrapping the whole thing in procedural code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Martin, basically I would like to see colors paired up just like the query result that I have done, but only applying a nested loop. I'm not sure if it is possible to produce that into two separate columns, if not one is ok.

Comment: SQL being a declarative language does not have a concept of a "nested loop". If you want to use a nested loop, just for the hell of it, you have to wrap SQL in procedural code, like PL/SQL (Oracle) or perl or whatever.